# Car make & model lookup?

Tags: database

I'm designing a used car sales website and the client would like for customers looking to sell their car to have the ability to enter their car registration number plate, and for the site to pull back the make and model automatically.

There are many sites that do this (http://www.halfords.com / http://www.gocompare.com / http://www.confused.com / etc)

But I'm drawing a blank with several hours of googling providing nothing of use.

Can anyone provide a clue?

### EDIT:

The sites listed allow a user to put their registration into the site, and it tells them what make and model the car is.

I wan't to replicate this functionality on the website I am designing.
OBVIOUSLY they have a giant database, or more likely access to a webservice somewhere which gives them the details.

But I cannot find said service or database.

Please can you provide information on where to look?

### EDIT 2:

Basically.. I'm after a UK version of this service: http://www.webservices.nl/en/1156/vehicle

Comment: I'm confused. You say that there are many sites that do what you want to do. What is the question? Are you trying to choose among those sites?

Comment: No.. I was trying to replicate the functionality of those sites on a customer's site.
The sites I list as examples allow a customer to enter their registration number and the site will identify their car make and model for them.

The site I was designing needed to also do this (so visitors to the site I was developing could put their reg number in, and the site would know the car make and model).

Comment: Would you be looking for an api such as offered by www.regcheck.org.uk ?

Answer (score 2):

The source for all this info is the DVLA. A quick google and look around their website produces: http://www.dft.gov.uk/dvla/data.aspx

Comment: unfortunately, they were my first call, and they are not the ones providing Halfords with their data (although they do provide the insurance companies). They also don't provide to sites like autotrader, so my customer's site will have no hope :/
but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sites' TOS don't explicitly forbid your site from connecting to it in background, you should be able to (from a legal and technical standpoint) write a script that connects to these sites in the background.

Best policy would be to contact these sites to find out if they allow this.  Even if their TOS doesn't state this to be a problem, there could be some legal issue that I'm not aware of.

There are lots of tutorials on doing this. For instance, using PHP & Curl, one could do this (example tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl)

Comment: hmm.. I'm not 100% convinced on the legal standpoint of doing this... good idea tho

Comment: Database rights and the legal issue of it not (normally) being their data to license. Most places license it from elsewhere (for a fee)

Comment: Just thinking of how Google pulls Yelp data in, I suppose as long as you give credit to the supplier AND that data is publicly accessible (and TOS doesn't forbid scraping), it could work. I think credit would be required regardless of TOS being available, assuming the site has a copyright notice in footer.  Be sure to cache this stuff so you're not putting excessive load on their server.  Another route might be to contact these government vendors and see if they are selling the information to anyone.  Seems like the US's right-to-view-public-data (I forget the Act) would force them to tell you